# Git project tracking in both solutions

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

There is a solution, it has a main project and a library project, on which the main one depends. The library project has its own separate repository on the git. I can’t figure out how to add a library project to this main solution so that it would be pulled together by the whole solution. The problem is that when the layout designer pulls the main project for himself, he naturally cannot launch it, he sees the following:
[image]

Here's how it looks for me:
[image]

How do I get Git to track the project in this solution as well?

Comment: Have you taken a look to submodules ?
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @Ôrel Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Make an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a submodule for this:

Create a repository for HTTPLibrary
Then create a repository for your main project and add HTTPLibrary as submodule with `git submodule add <httplib repo>`

More details https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules